# Apparent honorific use of 参る

Tags: etymology, honorifics, classical-japanese

I'm puzzled by the appearance of 参る in this [dictionary entry](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BF%E3%81%90%E3%81%97).

The example sentence is archaic:「こなたにてみぐしなど参る程に」

In the modern language, this becomes: こちらでお髪などおととのえになるころに。

Notice that the modern version uses an honorific verb おととのえになる. As I understand it, 参る is a humbling form in the contemporary language. Was it an honorific form in the past, or is there some other way to understand these sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Was it an honorific form in the past

Yes. According to [this 古語辞典](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%90%E3%82%8B):

> まゐ・る 【参る】
> [二]他動詞ラ行四段活用
> ④ **なさる。おやりになる。▽「す」の尊敬語。**
> 出典 源氏物語　若紫 「今宵（こよひ）はなほ静かに加持（かぢ）などまゐりて」 [訳] 今晩はやはり静かに加持などをなさって。